# Delete rows where "H:H" has positive values

Tags: vba, excel

I need to delete rows where the positive values begin in column H after sorting. I was trying to use the find feature. I know >0 does not work but not sure where to go from here. I can switch the sort to descending and search for "-" if I can figure out how to select upwards and delete.

```
    Source_Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Source_Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H:H"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Cells.Select

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:R65800")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Find(What:=">0", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems suited to a single field [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx).

```
Sub del_positives()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'turn off any exiting autofilter
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        'work with the block of cells radiating out from A1
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            'apply the positive number filter to column H
            .AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:=">0"
            'step off the header row
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                'determine if there are cells to delete
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(102, .Cells)) Then
                    'if there are, delete them
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
            'remove the filter
            .AutoFilter
            'if you still want to sort, then do so
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(8), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I've added a [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) in case you wanted to continue with a sorted output.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! It worked perfectly and I will be able to use this method for other reports.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, loop through each cell in the range. Double check that my `lastRow` is an accurate and sustainable way to get the last row in your project:

```
Sub t()
Dim lastRow as Long, i as Long
Dim myWS as worksheet
Dim mySourceWB as workbook
Dim cel as Range

Set mySourceWB = Source_Workbook ‘ you will probably need to tweak this
Set myWS = mySourceWB.Worksheets(“Sheet1”)

myWS.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=myWS.Range("H:H"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With myWS.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:R65800")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With ‘myWS.sort

With myWS
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,8).End(xlup).Row
    For i = lastRow to 1 ‘ change to 2, if you have headers
    If .cells(i,8).Value > 0 Then
        .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End if
    Next i
End with ‘myWS
End Sub
```

Comment: If these are sorted in xlAscending order then a `MATCH(1E-99, H:H)` can find the row containing the last non-positive number very quickly. Offset 1 row down and grab everything to the bottom should be quick.

Comment: @Jeeped - never thought of that, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne I tried this one first because it seemed closer to my coding style but I got stuck in the end. It wouldn't execute the second with statement. I am fairly new to vba so not sure why. I tried a number of different tweaks but it didn't work.

Comment: @chefAna - I wonder if it's the quote types I used accidentally in `"Sheet1"` when I declare `myWS`. Those should be straight quotes. Oh well, glad Jeeped got it!

Comment: No, I had used the generic "Sheet1" to preserve the integrity of my document so I didn't copy or paste or anything. It was in the 2nd with statement:  If .cells(i,8).Value > 0 Then
        .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete